# Polymorphic object fail when arrays are passed with arbitrary index range

Tags: arrays, fortran

I provide an example when converting a string to an integer array. I pass an array using an index range.The offset is being initiated by 0 rather than one, so the values in the array are being shifted.

```
s = "1,2,3,5,8"

Call str_to_num_tu (s, ",", tu(1:8))
$ Output: 
$ tu(1):   0 ; tu(2):   1 ; tu(3):   2

Call str_to_num_tu (s, ",", tu)
$ Output:
$ tu(i):   1 ; tu(2):   2 ; tu(3):   3
```

Here is my subroutine using an unlimited polymorphic variable.

```
Subroutine str_to_num_tu   &
  (                        &
    s, dl, tu, pos         &
  )  

Class(*), Intent (InOut) :: tu(:)

Character (len=*), Intent (In) :: s, dl
Character (len=*), Intent (In), Optional :: pos

Integer, Allocatable :: ipos(:)
Integer :: nf, npos, ip, i, j, k

 !!$ Sets tu. 
 !!$ s = "Pablo/Neruda"; tu = ["Pablo","Neruda"] 
 !!$ s = "0.2/1.3/1.5"; tu = [0.2,1.3,1.5] 
 nf = nfields (s, dl)

 Write (*,*) ""
 Write (*,*) "nf: ", nf, "; Size(tu): ", Size(tu)

     i = 1
     Do k = 1, nf-1
       j = Index (s(i:), dl)

       Select Type (tu)
       Type Is (Integer (Int32))
         Call str_to_num (s(i:i+j-2), tu(k))
         Write (*,*) Trim (s(i:))
         Write (*,*) "k: ",  k, "; tu(k): ", tu(k)
       End Select    !!$ tu 

       i = i + j

     End Do

     !!$ Gets last field.
     j = Index (s, dl, back=.true.)
     Write (*,*) "j:", j, "; nf:", nf 

     Select Type (tu)
     Type Is (Integer (Int32))
       Call str_to_num (s(j+1:), tu(nf))
     End Select    !!$ tu 

End Subroutine str_to_num_tu
```

Comment: show the declaration for tu in the main prpgram.

Comment: You do know that even a list-directed internal read of the string will get the integers into an array for you, don't you ?

Comment: Can confirm it is a gcc problem when using array ranges into a polymorphic objects. A problem with the offset being 0 rather than 1.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark. Can you elaborate on list-directed internal read please.

Comment: If you want to claim there is a fundamental  "problem" with gcc please provide a complete and preferably minimal example.

Comment: Yes, it is a fundamental "problem" with gcc when using polymorphic declaration and you pass an array which is defined by an index range. Just passing the array name produces no problems.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing -  my point is your question would be more useful if you could trim it down to a clean/minimal example. ( string conversion issues seem to be irrelevant and distracting ).

Comment: Yes, find an example and report it to the GCC bugzilla and don't forget the details about your compiler version, reporting it here is almost useless, eventhough some gfortran devs do come here AFAIK. I have a feeling that I some something like that there or among the patches, did you try the latest version of GCC 5?

Comment: I am setting the latest snapshot right now.

Comment: Same problem occurs using gcc-5

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on my earlier comment.  (I don't have Fortran on this computer so the syntax may be a little wonky.)  What I meant is that something like this

```
integer, dimension(6), allocatable :: arr
integer :: ios
character(len=:), allocatable :: str
...
arr = 0
str = "1,2,3,5,8"
read(str,*,iostat=ios) arr
```

will read the first 6 integers from `str` into the elements of `arr`.  As it happens `str` only has 5 integers so the last element of `arr` is left as `0`.  `iostat` is necessary here because an attempt to read more integers than `str` provides will otherwise produce an end-of-file error at run time.

Of course, this approach generalises to reals, characters and logicals too.  Fortran has, built-in, polymorphic reading of intrinsic types.  Up to a point.

Fortran will recognise blanks and spaces as *value-separators* (the Fortran standard uses the word *delimiter* to mean something else).  Note that by setting the `decimal` mode on an i/o statement to `comma` Fortran will recognise the comma as a decimal point and treat a semi-colon, `;`, as a value-separator.  Technically a slash is also a value-separator but it also causes termination of list-directed input of the record so doesn't really act like a value-separator.

If concerned about strings containing other value-separators I might write a function which took a string containing such, returned one with only whitespace, and then perform the internal read on that.

Comment: How does fortran define the delimiter?

Comment: fair point, if you want to handle arbitrary delimiters you would likely end up with something like your original approach.